# Magento Admin Edit Form Fields - Custom Model Field(s)

Tags: php, forms, magento, admin

Wanting to add a custom Model to be rendered in a custom Magento admin form. Just cant seem to get the source model to render any of the options. Couldn't really find anything on google as it was mostly to do with system/config source model examples. See code below

Model File (My/Module/Model/MyModel.php)

```
<?php
class My_Module_Model_MyModel extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
 static public function getOptionArray()
{

    $allow = array(
       array('value' => '1', 'label' => 'Enable'),
       array('value' => '0', 'label' => 'Disable'),
   );

   return $allow;
}
}
```

and my form tab file - Tab shows up with multiselect field, but its blank (My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Tab/Data.php)

```
<?php

class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Edit_Tab_Data extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

protected function _prepareForm(){ 


    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('module_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('module')->__('Module Information')));
    $object = Mage::getModel('module/module')->load( $this->getRequest()->getParam('module_id') );
    

    echo $object;
    
    
   
    $fieldset->addField('module_enabled', 'multiselect', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Allowed Module'),
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'module_enabled',
      'source_model' => 'My_Module_Model_MyModel',
      'after_element_html' => '<small>Select Enable to Allow</small>',
      'tabindex' => 1
    ));
    
    
    if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getModuleData() )
    {
          $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getModuleData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setModuleData(null);
    } elseif ( Mage::registry('module_data') ) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('module_data')->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
   }


  }
```

So I have other fields, tabs that all save the data etc but just cant get the values to render using a custom model inside the multiselect field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056140/magento-saving-multiselect-array-on-custom-model was also helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like method name in the source model is incorrect. Also, you probably don't need to extend `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` in source models.

Try this:

```
<?php
class My_Module_Model_MyModel
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => '1', 'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Enable')),
            array('value' => '0', 'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Disable')),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: and changed "source_model" to  'values' => Mage::getModel('module/mymodel')->toOptionArray(),

Answer (score 0):

<sub>OP's solution migrated from the question to an answer:</sub>

> updated the MyModel.php to get a foreach in a collection (CMS Pages
> for example)
>
> ```
> <?php
> class My_Module_Model_MyModel
> {
>  public function toOptionArray($withEmpty = false)
>  {
>     $options = array();
>     $cms_pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
>     foreach ($cms_pages as $value) {
>       $data = $value->getData();
>         $options[] = array(
>             'label' => ''.$data['title'].'('.$data['identifier'].')',
>             'value' => ''.$data['identifier'].''
>         );
>     }
>
>     if ($withEmpty) {
>         array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('module')->__('-- Please Select --')));
>     }
>
>     return $options;
> }
> ```
>
> and within My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Tab/Data.php I just
> removed "source_model" and replaced it with
>
> ```
> 'values' => Mage::getModel('module/mymodel')->toOptionArray(),
> ```
>
> Just to add, also had the issue of multiselect values not
> saving/updating the multiselect field on refresh/save on the edit
> page. To get this working, I edited the admin controller under the
> saveAction (or the action name to save the form data). See below my
> saveAction in the controller for the admin/backend located in
> My/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/ModuleController.php
>
> ```
>  public function saveAction() {
>     $model = Mage::getModel('module/module');
>     if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
>
>
>         $model = Mage::getModel('module/module');
>         $model->setData($data)
>             ->setModuleId($this->getRequest()->getParam('module_id'));
>
>         try {
>             if ($model->getCreatedTime() == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
>                 $model->setCreatedTime(now())->setUpdateTime(now());
>             } else {
>                 $model->setUpdateTime(now());
>             }
>           
>            
>           $ModuleEnabled = $this->getRequest()->getParam('module_enabled');
>           if (is_array($ModuleEnabled))
>             {
>             $ModuleEnabledSave = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getParam('module_enabled')); 
>             }
>             $model->setModuleEnabled($ModuleEnabledSave);
>           
>             //save form data/values per field
>             $model->save();
>
>             
>             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('module')->__('Item
> was successfully saved'));
>             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
>
>             if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
>                 $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('module_id' => $model->getModuleId()));
>                 return;
>             }
>             $this->_redirect('*/*/');
>             return;
>         } catch (Exception $e) {
>             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
>             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
>             $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('module_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('module_id')));
>             return;
>         }
>     }
>     Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('module')->__('Unable
>     to find item to save'));
>         $this->_redirect('*/*/');
>     }
> ```
>
> This saves an imploded array (ie 2, 3 ,6, 23, 28,) into the database
> value and renders the selected multiselect fields on the corresponding
> tab on refresh/update/save